# How to access nested form elements with a php script

Tags: php, html, forms, post, apache2

I am running an Apache2 webserver on my Raspberry PI. I want to send myself an email whenever a user decides to fill out and submit following HTML form.

```
<form action="submit_rsvp_form.php" class="rsvp-form ftco-animate">
                        <div class="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-field">
                                    <div class="select-wrap">
                                        <div class="icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><span class="ion-ios-arrow-down"></span></div>
                                            <select name="guests" id="" class="form-control">
                                                <option value="">Guests</option>
                                                <option value="">0</option>  
                                                <option value="">1</option>
                                                <option value="">2</option>
                                                <option value="">3</option>
                                                <option value="">4</option>
                                                <option value="">5</option>
                                         </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="submit" value="I am attending" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-4">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Here the referenced php script:

```
<?php
echo isset($_POST['email']);
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_to = "my_personal_email";
    $email_subject = "WEDDING RSVP";
    $first_name = $_POST['name']; 
    $email_from = $_POST['email'];
    $location = 'my_town'; 
    $address = 'my_address'; // required
    $guests = $_POST['guests'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message = "RSVP answer below.\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Location: ".clean_string($location)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Address: ".clean_string($address)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Guests: ".clean_string($guests)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>

  <div class="feedback">Great! We are looking forward to seeing you!</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

I got the PHP script off of StackOverflow and changed it a little.

The problem here is, that nothing is displayed when I press the button, not even the success HTML.

I was wondering if the problem lies in the structure of my HTML form..

Is there an obvious mistake I am making? I am not a PHP developer so I really do not know a lot about its specifics.

Thanks for helping

Comment: I should add, that I tried debugging with echo statements. The code never gets to the inner part of `if(isset($_POST['email']))`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding `method="POST"` to the `<form>` tag..